# How to find out currently used DNS namesevers on iPhone

Tags: iphone

How to find out currently used DNS nameservers on iPhone? Using SDk 4.
Basically i am looking for an equivalent function on iPhone OS to GetNetworkParams on Windows

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not aware of any objective C APIs included that can do this, so you could always resort to C calls to handle this.. See a guide like : [Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)